# ScrollTo not working with scroll-snap and 100vh container

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll-snap, js-scrollto

When I have a `.sections` container with several `.section` elements inside, and setup scroll-snap, it will *ONLY* work if I give the section a fixed height of 100vh. Without the height, the scroll-snap will not work. This is fine, except without the fixed height, `scrollTo` works correctly, and when I add the height to the section, `scrollTo` no longer works.

Here is an example. You can comment out the `height: 100vh;` line in the `.section` CSS and see that clicking anywhere will scroll down to section #3, but with the height turned on, it won't scroll.

I have tried to `console.log` the position it is scrolling to and it is correct, but the scroll never actually takes place. Any ideas as to why this is not behaving the way I would like?

NOTE: I am seeing this behavior in the latest Chrome. I have not tested another browser.

```js
// Click on document to scroll to section 3
document.body.onclick = function() {
    console.log('SCROLLING...');
    const el = document.getElementById('s3');
    const pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollTo(0, pos.top); 
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sections {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    /**
     * Adding the below line breaks scrollto, removing 
     * it breaks scroll-snap....
     */
    height: 100vh; 
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid deeppink;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;

    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="sections">
            <div class="section" id="s1">SECTION 1</div>
            <div class="section" id="s2">SECTION 2</div>
            <div class="section" id="s3">SECTION 3</div>
            <div class="section" id="s4">SECTION 4</div>
            <div class="section" id="s5">SECTION 5</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to scroll inside `.sections` when making the height:100vh and not the window (`document.querySelector('.sections').scrollTo(0, pos.top);` should do it I guess)

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Temani Afif for the comment. They correctly pointed out that I cannot scroll using the body, I need to scroll using the `.sections` container.

Here is a working example now:

```js
// Click on document to scroll to section 3
document.body.onclick = function() {
    console.log('SCROLLING...');
    const el = document.getElementById('s3');
    const pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const sections = document.querySelector('.sections');
    sections.scrollTo(0, pos.top); 
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sections {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh; 
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid deeppink;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;

    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="sections">
            <div class="section" id="s1">SECTION 1</div>
            <div class="section" id="s2">SECTION 2</div>
            <div class="section" id="s3">SECTION 3</div>
            <div class="section" id="s4">SECTION 4</div>
            <div class="section" id="s5">SECTION 5</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```